# score displaying system without using bitmap

Tags: libgdx

how to make a score displaying system without using bitmap in libgdx.
I making a fluppy bird remake
somone can explaim me in details?

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use a bitmap? In case you are unaware, there is a program called `Hiero`, it's supplied with LibGDX that creates a bitmap from any font in seconds. Then all you have to do is load that inside your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use the Freetype Library -> [See here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gdx-freetype)

First you have to include the library into your project as described in the article.

Then in your constructor you define the font object using your desired font.

```
FileHandle handle = Gdx.files.internal("YOUR_FONT.TTF");
FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(handle);
FreeTypeFontParameter parameter = new FreeTypeFontParameter();
parameter.size = 50;
parameter.flip = true;
BitmapFont font = generator.generateFont(parameter);
```

And finally in your `render()`Method you draw the text.

```
font.draw(batch, "SCORE: " + score, x, y);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you do not want to use bitmap font because it doesn't center correctly on the screen, you can take a look at [libgdx's scene 2d API's Label](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Label.html).